# how to rectify pip subroutines installation error

Tags: python, pycharm, chatbot, subroutine, chatterbot

[It displays an error in pycharm for the installation of chatterbot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g6fe.png). I tried to install pip-chatterbot to create a chatbot but it throws an error saying pip subroutines did not run successfully. need a solution to install and run chatterbot successfully

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.